# Cannot access WHM and SSH/root after a configuration in Host Access Control

Tags: linux, ip, cpanel, whm, ip-blocking

I have a major problem and I am at my wit's end. First, I added my IP (like 172.32.1.0/255.255.255.0) to allow access for ssh, whm and cpanel in WHM -> Host Access Control. Then, I added all IP to deny access for them. However, after saved changes, I lost access all of them. Now, If I try to login WHM, I see that:

> **HTTP error 401**
>
> You do not have permission to access this page.

Also, I cannot access SSH. I don't know what to do. Maybe if I restart server, the problem will be solved? Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A few possible options here.

1. Contact your web host support and ask them to whitelist your IP or turn off HAC - whichever option you prefer.
2. Go to the nearest WiFi hotspot, connect from there, remove your IP in HAC.
3. Use VPN to connect to your server.
4. Ask someone you know and trust to log in and remove your IP (guide him/her via Skype screen sharing if needed).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to contact your server provider to edit /etc/hosts.allow and /etc/hosts.deny file, OR if you have KVM access, then you can edit it through KVM console